# iOS upgrading from applicationDidFinishLaunching to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am redoing some old code (using Cocos2d v0.99) and it is still using `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and want to know if there is anything I should be concerned about when switching it to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

All I did was add a `return YES` to the bottom of the method, and then I swapped out this:
 `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application`

for this:
 `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Everything seems to be working fine, but just wondering if there is anything I need to check or look into that might popup later on.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nah, you should be fine. I do it with some of my apps except I return 0. But there shouldn't be any side effects to doing so.

Comment: OK thanks.. wasn't sure if there was something else I needed to be aware of but seems to be working fine without any issues.